# Image (location pins) on top of background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have location pins on top of background image.
but when its responsive pins location chages.
i want set pins at specific position of images

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ncX/qyL/ncXqyLdcB.png" class="pin1">
  <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ncX/qyL/ncXqyLdcB.png" class="pin2">
</div>
```

css

```
body {
  background: url(http://connect.homes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/200392710-0012.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
/*  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;*/
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
.pin1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    top: 10%;
    left: 28%;
  }
.pin2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
  }
```

i am trying to set position but its not working

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a background image as it's not responsive in the same way as positioning. Use an **actual** inline image in a wrapper and position your pins on that.

Here's an example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.map {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.map img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  width: 8%;
  height: 8%;
  background-image: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/0/g/a/W/E/map-pin-red.svg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
}

#pin-1 {
  top: 29%;
  left: 36%;
}

.box:hover>.pin-text {
  display: block;
}

.pin-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 75%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
}

.pin-text h3 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Pleasant_View_housing_development%2C_Missoula%2C_Montana_-_panoramio.jpg/800px-Pleasant_View_housing_development%2C_Missoula%2C_Montana_-_panoramio.jpg" alt="" />
  <div id="pin-1" class="box">
    <div class="pin-text">
      <h3>My House</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```